# How can i tokenize a sentence starting with spaces in C

Tags: c

I am trying to tokenize a sentence that starts with spaces but I get segmentation fault. I am trying to skip the spaces and store the words. Is there an alternative built-in function to achieve this?

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

[...]

    char *buff = "  push me", *token;
    
    token = strtok(buff, " \n");
    while (token) {
        printf("%s", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }

[...]
```

Comment: doesn't strtok change the buffer?  But you point to a string constant.  Probably in read only segment.

Comment: do `char buff[] = ...` instead of `char *buff = ...` to get a writable string.

Comment: Change buff from a pointer to an array — `char buff[] = “  push me”;` — and you should be okay.

Answer (score 1):

change to this

```
char buff[100], *token;

strcpy(buff,"  push me");
```

Before you were pointing to a string constant with the buff variable.  The compiler will put this in a segment that is read only.  If you try to write to that segment you get a segmentation fault.  So in the code above we allocate space in read/write memory to store the string and then copy it in.

Comment: Or `char buff[] = "  push me";` — initialization rather than a separate assignment via `strcpy()`.

Comment: Yes @JonathanLeffler -- that would work.  I wrote it this way to make it clearer, what the variable type was and show the data movement.  Sometimes you don't write the shortest code to be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

`buff` points to a string literal that usually cannot be modified.
`strspn` and `strcspn` can be used to parse the sub-strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void) {
    char *buff = "  push me";
    char *token = buff;
    size_t span = 0;

    if ( ! buff) {
        return 1;
    }

    while ( *token) {
        token += strspn ( token, " \r\n\t\f\v"); // count past whitespace
        span = strcspn ( token, " \r\n\t\f\v"); // count non-whitespace
        if ( span) {
            printf ( "%.*s\n", (int)span, token); // precision field to print token
        }
        token += span; // advance token pointer
    }
}
```

Comment: why run strspn twice?  also doen't this miss the first token if it does not start with whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

`strtok()`, like others, are "library functions", not "built-in".

Very intelligent people wrote these functions expecting they would  be used in clean, elegant and terse ways. I believe this is what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char buf[] = "  push me"; // don't point at a "string literal'

    for( char *tok = buf; (tok = strtok( tok, " \n") ) != NULL; tok = NULL )
        printf( "%s\n", tok ); // added '\n' for clarity

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
push
me
```